# Suppress some Spring boot specific logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I am running a springboot application and I see that Spring boot logs every method call that is done. That means I get the following lines for every single method called:

```
Jan 31 08:40:28 hostname java: Jan 31, 2022 8:40:28 AM com.whatever.ClassName methodName
```

How do I suppress these kind of logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default loglevel springboot uses by setting it up into application.properties (or application.yml)

For example, you can go with (assuming you are using application.properties)

```
logging.level.root=warn
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate=error
```

So you get debug messages for the web part, but root logging (everything but springframework.web) is set to warning, and hibernate logs only to error.

You can see more of this into the docs
[https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20Spring%20Boot%20logs,for%20example%2C%20in%20your%20application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20Spring%20Boot%20logs,for%20example%2C%20in%20your%20application).

Comment: If I do that, the logs within the method also disappear. I don't want that. I have tried the approach above and then in the class, I have a logger with name "somethingDifferentThanTheClass". When I set the root logger to warn/error and then logging.level.somethingDifferentThanTheClass=info I get the logs I want but again the logs about the class method calls appears again.

Comment: I guess then you are getting them on INFO level, right? What logging framework are you using? SLF4J? Do you have any AOP configured? I don't see calls to methods logged. Can you post your config?

Comment: It seems this is an issue with the formatter. The formatter seems to print logs into two lines with the first line containing this undesired part and the second line containing the logs in question. I can see that with basic jshell test:

jshell> logger.info("Another test")
Jan 31, 2022 1:03:20 PM REPL.$JShell$18 do_it$
INFO: Another test

Comment: yes, it was an issue with the formatter, for i was using java built in logger with spring boot.